# Passing data back from ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to passing data between TableViewController and ViewController the TableViewController passing data back form ViewController 
Program is not found my 'minTable'

My protocol code: 
       import Foundation

```
protocol SaveUnits {
    func save (value: Double)
}
```

My Table class:

```
class UnitsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

 var minTable = Double()
 var delegate: SaveUnits?

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let  tableCell = moneyArray[indexPath.row]

        minTable = tableCell.val

        delegate?.save(value: minTable)

        unitsText  = tableCell.name

        let _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

My ViewController class:

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SaveUnits {

var min = 1
   func save(value: Double) {
        min = minTable // use of unresolved indentifier 'minTable'
    }
```

my delegete passing data:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
            (segue.destination as? UnitsTableViewController)?.delegate = self
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `ViewController` doesn't know anything about `minTable`. `minTable` is property of the `UnitsTableViewController`. You passing it like argument to `save` function. So inside it function it called `value`. You should write:

```
func save(value: Double) {
  min = value
}
```

Comment: my  min  does not want to take the value from the table

Comment: min has only  min = 1

Comment: Does `save` func get called?

Comment: what do you mean 'get called' ?

Comment: If you make a breakpoint on row `min = value`. Does execution of the app stops at this breakpoint?

Comment: I'm just asking if you set delegate to something? Cause I can't see any row of code starting with `delegate = ...`

Comment: var delegate: SaveUnits? and  delegate?.save(value: minTable)

Comment: it just does not go in these functions

Comment: If so, you should set your delegate to something. In case `ViewController` presenting `UnitsTableViewController`: in `ViewController` class override `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` and write in it `(segue.destinationViewController as? UnitsTableViewController)?.delegate =  self`

Comment: sorry, I write override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
            (segue.destination as? UnitsTableViewController)?.delegate = self
    } in ViewControlle, but it's nothing changed. My program does work

Comment: How do you show your `UnitsTableViewController` form `ViewController` ? Using segues in interface builder or programmatically? If second add code that opens second controller

Comment: ' let unitController  = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UnitsTableViewController") as! UnitsTableViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(unitController, animated: true)'  so I turn on the TableView

Comment: my buttnUnits `  @IBAction func buttnUnits(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        
        unitsText.titleLabel?.text = nameUnits
        
        let unitController  = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UnitsTableViewController") as! UnitsTableViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(unitController, animated: true)
    }
`

Comment: Ok, then you don't need `prepareForSegue` cause you don't use segue. Delete prepareForSegue and modify your code. Add ` unitController.delegate = self` just before before `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(unitController‌​, animated: true)`

Comment: No. Replace IBAction with this `@IBAction func buttnUnits(_ sender: AnyObject) { unitsText.titleLabel?.text = nameUnits let unitController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UnitsTableViewController") as! UnitsTableViewController unitController.delegate = self self.navigationController?.pushViewController(unitController‌​, animated: true) } `

Comment: Grand thanks it worked)
but I can not change the name of a button

Comment: protocol SaveUnits {
    func save (value: Double)
    func saveName(name: String)
}
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let  tableCell = moneyArray[indexPath.row]
        
        minTable = tableCell.val
       
        delegate?.save(value: minTable)
        
        unitsText  = tableCell.name
        
        delegate?.saveName(name: unitsText)
    
        let _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        
        
    }

Comment: var nameUnits = "" ,   func saveName(name: String) {
        nameUnits = name
    }

Comment: make an @IBOutlet for your button. I assume it will be named `@IBOutlet weak var showUnitButton: UIButton` then modify `func saveName` and add this line of code: `showUnitButton.setTitle(name, for: .normal)`